# Set root view controller from another view controller

Tags: ios, swift2

I am trying to implement a log out button inside another view controller. The log out button currently removes all user defaults and clears any tokens from the keychain however I do not know how to display the home view controller and remove all other views from memory?

```
let rootView: HomeViewController = HomeViewController()
if let window = self.window{
    window.rootViewController = rootView
}
```

doesn't seem to work inside another view controller.

Thanks

Comment: How about having a segue to home view controller

Comment: Alternatively, if what you actually want to do is to fully change to a new root view controller, you can do this through your AppDelegate's .window property, like this: `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(named: "NewStoryboard", bundle: nil)
let newVC = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController
UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate.window.rootViewController = newVC`

Comment: you can't simply change the root view controller without either dismissing the current one or presenting a new one!!!

Comment: Understood. How do you suggest I manage a log out button that needs to take the user back to the home view controller and remove all that are currently in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
        if let window = self.view.window {
            window.rootViewController = HomeViewController()
        }
```

as `window` is not member of `UIViewController`, you need to access the `window` using member `view` of `UIViewController`.